# Como converter um vetor de objetos para outro objeto?

Tags: typescript

Queria saber se existe alguma forma simples de converter um vetor de objetos A para um vetor de objetos do tipo B, que seguem a segunda estrutura:

Objeto A

```
{
    aId: number;
    aNome: string;
    aDesc: string;
}
```

Objeto B

```
{
    bId: number;
    bNome: string;
}
```

Eu vou receber um vetor de A e quero passar um vetor de B, existe algum método simples de fazer isso?

Comment: Por que tanto negativo?

Comment: Me faço a mesma pergunta... Preciso melhorar a descrição de alguma coisa? .___.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É fácil, só usar um `map()`

```
var result = arr.map((item) => new ObjetoB(item.aId, item.aNome));
```

Código completo — Usei construtores nas classes pra facilitar a leitura.

```
class ObjetoA {
    constructor(public id, public nome, public desc) {}
}

class ObjetoB {
    constructor(public id, public nome) {}
}

var arr = [new ObjetoA(1, 'A', 'AA'), new ObjetoA(2, '2A', '2AA')];

var result = arr.map((item) => new ObjetoB(item.id, item.nome));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Mas eu sempre tenho que resolver isso no construtor? Não existe nenhuma forma automática dele associar, né?

Comment: Automática não. Tem como fazer com serialização, mas é muito mais comum isso ser mais problema do que solução.

Comment: Minha dúvida era se essa era a forma mais simples... Parece que sim, vou aceitar como resposta.

Comment: @FelipeAvelar O que dá pra entender da sua pergunta é que queres pegar um array e transformar todos os itens dele pra outro array. Ela não fala especificamente em cópia.

Comment: Não é uma cópia que eu quero, é exatamente isso que você fez, só queria ver se tinha uma maneira mais simples, mas pelo que eu pesquisei e pela tua resposta, realmente parece ser o caminho mais simples. (: